# eslint with @stencil/eslint-plugin throw "Cannot read property 'typeAnnotation' of undefined

Tags: eslint, stenciljs

After adding `@stencil/plugin-eslint` to my eslint config `extends` section, eslint has started throwing the following error:

```
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 7.11.0

TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeAnnotation' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a type annotation to my property fixed this:

```
@Component({
    tag: 'my-component',
    shadow: true,
})
export class MyComponent implements ComponentWillLoad {

    // @Element() host; // before
    @Element() host: HTMLMyComponentElement;  // after
```

Additionally, adding this to my `tsconfig.json` -> `compilerOptions` caused this situation to be raised as an error earlier:

```
"noImplicitAny": true,
```